# Update a column using a value from the same row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a SQL command in Oracle to update the value of "LOADDATE" to equal the value of "UPDATEDATE" on my table.  What I have here works:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE LOAD_SETTINGS 
    SET 
      LOADDATE = (
        SELECT UPDATEDATE 
        FROM LOAD_SETTINGS
        WHERE
          MODEL = 'A001'
          AND OBJECT = 'A'
      )
    WHERE
      MODEL = 'A001'
      AND OBJECT = 'A';
  COMMIT;
END;
```

The one thing I know for sure about Oracle is that there is a lot that I do not know.  Is there a better way to do this using any features of Oracle that I may not be familiar with?  Perhaps without having to use a subquery?  Or is this the the way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the where clause on the subquery is the same where on the outer there's no need for the subselect just reference the column directly

```
UPDATE LOAD_SETTINGS 
SET 
  LOADDATE = UPDATEDATE 

WHERE
  MODEL = 'A001'
  AND OBJECT = 'A';
```

Comment: Wow. I was WAY overthinking that one.  Clearly, it's time for me to take a break.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE LOAD_SETTINGS 
SET    LOADDATE = UPDATEDATE 
WHERE  MODEL LIKE 'A001'
AND    OBJECT LIKE 'A';
```

Since `Model` and `Object` are varchar it is good to use `LIKE` instead of `=`.